# Nativescript different page when share intent

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want other applications to be able to share to my application different actions, and I want to have different pages showing for each action, how I do that ?

Imagine I have a music application with sharing action "add to playlist" and second action "play now" the play now will open the angular player page, while the add to playlist will open the playlist page , how can i achieve this scenario ? ( I'm using NS angular)

Comment: You will have to read the intent data from the activity and act accordingly upon launch.

Comment: By the way in angular app, what's the best place to put the code to read intent, is main.ts good ? So after I read it how I redirect to the desired page ? Finally if my action is not visual (not launching any page just processing ) how I do that ? Do you have code snippets examples for these scenarios ?

Comment: Perhaps you could have a loading / processing route if it's only processing and navigate to default page. You may write the code in app component.